# Php Comments used to pass arguments

Tags: php

I've seen an interesting code base recently, where some arguments were passed to methods via comments.
It looked something like

```
/*
 * @attribute default-method
 */
```

which would of course, declare the default method for a class being instantiated.

What is this? How is it done? Is there an example of this anywhere?

It was being used to control the format of returns, etc, so it certainly looked very interesting, and would certainly remove a lot of crap from classes I create.

Comment: As far as I know it doesn't do anything. Does the code actually stop working when you remove that line?

Comment: That's only for documentation purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others has stated, it can be used to generate documentation.

**However**, you can certainly implement application logic (often reffered to as attributes or annotations) using this style of comments. Consider the following example:

```
<?php
/**
 * @Foo Bar
 */
function sum($a, $b) {
  return $a + $b;  
}

$function = new ReflectionFunction('sum');
$attributes = $function->getDocComment();

var_dump($attributes);
// string(29) "/** * @attribute Foo Bar */"
```

You can then parse that comment and do whatever you want with the information.

In fact, [Doctrine](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.0.x/reference/annotations-reference.html) uses this "pattern" heavily.

Answer (score 6):

The arguments weren't passed to methods via comments; the comments are making use of (most likely) [PHPDoc](http://www.phpdoc.org/) to allow for the generation of API documentation (and to make it easy for developers to see what's going on when they look at the souce).

Is this the sort of thing you're talking about?:

```
/**
 * Set the data
 *
 * @access public
 * @param string $field
 * @param mixed $value
 */
public function __set($field, $value)
{
  $this->_data[$field] = $value;
}

/**
 * Get the data
 *
 * @access public
 * @param string $field
 * @return mixed
 */
public function __get($field)
{
  return isset($this->_data[$field]) ? $this->_data[$field] : NULL;
}
```

If so, you will notice that the parameters are still being passed, and the return values returned, as normal. It's just that PHPDoc is being used to document the code.

Comment: I use netbeans often for development. And even it after typing `/**`will automatically add the arguments from the method it proceeds to the comment.

Answer (score 0):

It's actually two asterisks

```
/**
 * @attribute blah
 */
```

See [PHP Documentor](http://www.phpdoc.org/)

Answer (score 0):

The comments are just an adaptation to javadoc. Basically a third party software can easily parse through the classes and able to pic out comments and method signatures right from the comment and generate a pretty html or pdf documentation. As previous poster has mention, look at phpdoc, thats one of the third party software that would use the comments.